# Add javascript library to Octopress posts?

Tags: blogs, octopress

For different posts (generated through `rake new_post[my_post]`), I want to add a javascript function that is to be only included in that post, and nowhere else on the blog.

I can do this by hand-editing the `public/my_post/index.html` file but then every time I do a `rake generate`, I will have to do this again.

Is there a built in way to make this happen in Octopress?

Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In 2.1 you will be able to inject per page/post  JavaScript or CSS assets into the header by setting some vars in the yaml front matter.

Currently you can simply insert a link or script tag inside of the post or page itself and it will be loaded in place. Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/file.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/file.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you needed `this.js` and `that.js` in a post save them under the newly created `/javascripts/custom/` directory.

Than in your default layout add, inside the `<head>` tag, something like:

```
{% if page.custom_javascript %}
    {% for js in page.custom_javascript %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/custom/{{ js }}"></script>    
    {% endfor%}
{% endif %}
```

Finally you can inject per-post javascript simply adding to the post YAML front-matter the field `custom_javascript`:

```
---
layout: post
title: "Insert javascript inside head with Octopress"
custom_javascript: [this.js, that.js]
---
```

Of course you can use a similar approach for others things you need to inject into the `<head>`.