# Embed JavaScript/SVG data visualizations in Octopress post with proper alignment?

Tags: svg, d3.js, embed, blogs, octopress

In a post on my Octopress blog, I'm trying to embed some basic data visualizations I developed using D3.js. I understand how to add a script to a post ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764957/how-to-add-a-script-in-an-octopress-post) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965506/add-javascript-library-to-octopress-posts) cover that well enough), so I'm able to display the visualizations.

My problem is the alignment of the visualizations--they appear at the very bottom of the blog, outside the post itself (I'd include a screenshot, but I don't have enough reputation points to share images). When I inspect the HTML elements, I see that the two visualizations are SVG elements (as they should be) at the bottom, separate from div#content and div.entry-content (where the rest of the post content appears), and later than the footer and sidebar.

**Is there a simple way to embed these visualizations on Octopress?**

Comment: I've not worked with octopress before but if you're embedding your `svg` using `d3.select('body').append('svg')`, then try changing it to `d3.select('.entry-content').append('svg')`. If your script is inserting the svg *after* the markdown is compiled, then I think that should do it.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks!